# django running with gunicorn and nginx: 400 bad request

Tags: python, django, curl, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my django version 1.6 project using nginx and gunicorn. In my server, I added my project nginx file:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/myproject-error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/myproject-access.log;
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name <domain_name>;
       root <path_to_my_root_project>;

       location /static/ {
           root <path_to_my_root_project>;
           expires max;
           add_header Pragma public;
          add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
      }

      location / {
          proxy_pass_header Server;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Schema $scheme;
          proxy_connect_timeout 10;
          proxy_read_timeout 10;

          proxy_pass http://localhost:8333/;
      }
      error_page 500 502 503 504 /static/50x.html;
}
```

In my django settings file, I set static paths:

```
# Static
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And the I run gunicorn as following:

```
$ gunicorn_django -b localhost:8333
!!!
!!! WARNING: This command is deprecated.
!!!
!!!     You should now run your application with the WSGI interface
!!!     installed with your project. Ex.:
!!!
!!!         gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application
!!!
!!!     See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/
!!!     for more info.
!!!
```

So when I run a curl on my server `curl localhost`, I get `<h1>Bad Request (400)</h1>` and the logs don't say much further than `127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2014:14:38:57 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "curl/7.26.0"`

And gunicorn stays still, as if no request is sent to it.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I run gunicor: `gunicorn myproject.wsgi -b localhost:8333`
The `curl localhost` returns my static/50x.html error page. And I got this in nginx logs:

```
2014/10/18 15:06:31 [error] 16037#0: *32 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: servername.local.fr, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8333/", host: "localhost"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one tells you what to do.

```
!!!     You should now run your application with the WSGI interface
!!!     installed with your project. Ex.:
!!!
!!!         gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application
```

NGINX is working fine, the gunicorn just isn't receiving your request.

Just to to your project dir and run gunicorn with proper parameters as described here: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#gunicorn-django

Comment: `WARNING: This command is deprecated.` I thought it is just depreacated and thus works. Otherwise it'd be and error message

Comment: @smarber you should try using siply `gunicorn` for running this.

Comment: @smarber Are you sure the gunicorn is running? Try this:
`ps aux | grep -i gunicorn`
...and this:
`sudo netstat -lputn`

Comment: ps returns this:

`username    16231  0.0  0.5  50856 12140 pts/0    S+   15:20   0:00 /home/username/Documents/projects/env/bin/python /home/username/Documents/projects/env/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi -b localhost:8333
username    16236  0.0  0.8  59000 16580 pts/0    S+   15:20   0:00 /home/username/Documents/projects/env/bin/python /home/bilou/Documents/django/projects/env/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi -b localhost:8333
username    16319  0.0  0.0   7848   904 pts/8    S+   15:23   0:00 grep --color=auto -i gunicorn`

Comment: `netstat -lputn | grep -i gunicorn` returns nothing

Comment: Is that normal that two gunicorn processes running at the same time?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's all about gunicorn, because I can run my project with debug=True, in which case everything works well. Plus nginx's good.